# can’t import public pgp keys on tails

Tags: tails, key

i’m trying to import public pgp keys on tails but it’s suddenly not working? i used to copy the public key into the text editor, save it as an .asc file, then double click it. a little dialog box would come up saying it had been important and i would see the key on my gnuPG key ring. now when i do it, the dialog box still comes up but i don’t see they key in the key ring afterwards. i’ve also tried opening the text file with the import key, as well as copying and pasting into the passwords and keys window and clicking “import”. nothing works, please help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally you should open a bug with tails, but this [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/seahorse-nautilus/-/issues/4) has already been opened and isn't fixed yet.
2. Open a terminal, go to where you saved the key and run the following:

   gpg --import your-key.asc